# Sync data from GridView to local database

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am trying to insert data to local database using below code, I guess my code read the GridView correctly, but after the for loop, an error occurred

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'The parameterized query '(@C1 nvarchar(4000),@C2 nvarchar(4000),@C3 nvarchar(4000),@C4 nv' expects the parameter '@C1', which was not supplied.

Can anyone help with this?

```
private void SavetodatabaseBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string connectionstring = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["BondAnalysis.Properties.Settings.BondDataBaseConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

    SqlConnection Con = new SqlConnection(connectionstring);

    SqlCommand com;
    string str;

    Con.Open();

    str = "INSERT INTO BondData VALUES(@C1, @C2, @C3, @C4)";
    com = new SqlCommand(str, Con);

    for (int index = 0; index<dataGridView1.Rows.Count; index++)
    {
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@C1", dataGridView1.Rows[index].Cells[0].Value);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@C2", dataGridView1.Rows[index].Cells[1].Value);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@C3", dataGridView1.Rows[index].Cells[2].Value);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@C4", dataGridView1.Rows[index].Cells[3].Value);

        com.ExecuteNonQuery();

        com.Parameters.Clear();
    }

    Con.Close();
}
```

Comment: Does you DGV have a blank rows at bottom (to allow edit).  You can't add the blank row so for loop should be index<dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1

Comment: thanks @jdweng error disappeared but I am checking the database table after executing the program it still empty, data didn't saved on the database table

Comment: I assume you are using SSMS to verify that the data was written correctly.  Either you are looking in the wrong database on the server, the connection string is writing to a different Server, or you need to REFRESH in SSMS.  I normally just close SSMS and open again to make sure SSMS get refresh as a first debug attempt.  If not then your connection string in the configuration is wrong.

Comment: thanks @jdweng first comment solved the error and the second one explained more, as I am still learning I will try to dig deep in what you said, thanks again dear

Comment: You should check out [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) and stop using `.AddWithValue()` - it can lead to unexpected and surprising results...